# Playing video with notification

Tags: objective-c, ios6, mpmovieplayercontroller

I am using the following to play a video named intro

```
- (IBAction)PlayIntro:(id)sender {
    NSString *videoPath = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"intro" ofType:@"m4v"];
    introplayer = [[MPMoviePlayerViewController alloc] initWithContentURL:[NSURL fileURLWithPath:videoPath]];
    [self presentMoviePlayerViewControllerAnimated:introplayer];
}
```

I am having trouble setting up a notification so that once the video is finished playing the following would take place `[self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"IntroS" sender:sender];` any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You should set up KVO for your MPMoviePlayerController. When the state of the movie changes, this fires giving you a chance to compare total playback time with the current playback time.

Given your snippet of code, this line will give you the current playback value:

```
NSLog(@"Movie player state: %g", introplayer.currentPlaybackTime);
```

[I provided a brief overview](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14703985/how-to-reload-text-inside-uitablecell-using-afnetworking/14704316#14704316) on how KVO works with an example unrelated to video playback.

Though the topic is unrelated to video, it works just the same regardless of what variable you're watching using KVO.